# how to make nested for loop print only once in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, pretty-print

I am trying to make my for loop print the request only once but it seems to do it twice. How do I prevent this?

```
import json

list_1 = ['name1','name2',]
list_2 = ['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2',]

username = 'john'
password = 'test_password'

for x in list_1:
    for y in list_2:
        x = {'device_type': 'juniper', 'ip': y, 'username': username, 'password': password, 'port': 9822,'verbose': False,}
        print (json.dumps(x, indent=1))
```

**Desired result**

```
        {
 "device_type": "juniper",
 "ip": "1.1.1.1",
 "password": "test_password",
 "port": 9822,
 "verbose": false,
 "username": "john"
}
{
 "device_type": "juniper",
 "ip": "2.2.2.2",
 "password": "test_password",
 "port": 9822,
 "verbose": false,
 "username": "john"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the inner loop is happening twice.

You have 2 JSON objects, and they both have different `"ip"` keys, I would push them to an array in the loop, then print the element I want after the loop is completed, that way you have more control over what is printed, and you also have a reference to it if you need it later on.

Also you're using the variable x in 2 different contexts here, the second x should be named something else.

Comment: Thanks MrHaze, would you be able to show me a example?

Comment: I would be, but don't you want try it out first?

Comment: Try creating a list, and use the `append()` function to append `x` to the list

Comment: So you want me to iterate through a list and make a list inside the loop again? I guess I am not following this correctly.

Comment: Instead of your print, just put them all in a list.
After the loop print list[0]

Answer (score 0):

This gave me what I wanted

```
import json
import itertools

list_1 = ['name1','name2',]
list_2 = ['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2',]

username = 'john'
password = 'test_password'

for x, y  in zip(list_1,list_2):
    x = {'device_type': 'juniper', 'ip': y, 'username': username, 'password': password, 'port': 9822,'verbose': False,}
    print (json.dumps(x, indent=1))
```